# JS: Changing Color of Slider Rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I am using the following slider for a program, and I want to be able to have sliders of different slider colors when I instantiate the slider. Currently, I see that the slider color is defined in .css file (d3.slider.css). 
http://sujeetsr.github.io/d3.slider/

How would I change the slider color value such that I can call multiple sliders with each a different starting color like shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the colors in these classes dragger-outer and dragger-inner for each slider

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 css styles I see being applied which you need to override.

- .d3slider-rect-value for the slider bar color, and,
- .dragger-outer for the slider head.

You can override these styles in your css(which will affect all your sliders). 
Otherwise in your JS code get above elements for your sliders and apply the styles dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Your circle code elements are here

```
<circle class="dragger-outer" r="10" transform="translate(0,6)"></circle>
<circle class="dragger-inner" r="4" transform="translate(0,6)"></circle>
```

then your css classes are here

```
.dragger-inner {
    fill: #65b042;
    stroke: none;
}

.dragger-outer {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: #000;
}
```

you can add more classes like above with different colors. if you want to create 6 circle you have to create 12 classes for that (use different names like .dragger-inner-red).